# Odoo 10 odoo.py: command not found, odoo.py: No such file or directory

Tags: odoo-10

from the docs:

```
Creating a basic module
In Odoo, tasks are performed by creating modules.

Modules customize the behavior of an Odoo installation, either by adding new behaviors or by altering existing ones (including behaviors added by other modules).

Odoo's scaffolding can setup a basic module. To quickly get started simply invoke:

$ ./odoo.py scaffold Academy my-modules
```

result:

```
$ ./odoo.py scaffold Academy my-modules
-bash: ./odoo.py: No such file or directory

$ python ./odoo.py scaffold Academy my-modules
python: can't open file './odoo.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

$ sudo python ./odoo.py scaffold Academy my-modules
python: can't open file './odoo.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

$ odoo.py scaffold Academy my-modules
odoo.py: command not found

$ python odoo.py scaffold Academy my-modules
python: can't open file 'odoo.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

$ sudo python odoo.py scaffold Academy my-modules
python: can't open file 'odoo.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I installed odoo 10 on a ubuntu 16.04 virtual box according to the steps in https://www.getopenerp.com/install-odoo-10-on-ubuntu-16-04/

I did `find | grep odoo.py` in my installation folder and it came back empty.

Answer (score 3):

The correct command for odoo 10 is

```
$ sudo ./odoo-bin scaffold Academy my-modules
```

and the correct docs are in https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/howtos/website.html

Comment: What version of odoo are you using?

Comment: In fact your solution works the way you described, it was me who did a mistake. +1